# Setup several Laravel 5 projects in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, laravel

I'm trying to setup my httpd.conf to be able to run several laravel projects in a subdirectory without constantly updating my httpd.conf for each project.

For example,

I'd like to be able to hit my site 127.0.0.1/my_projects and have several dynamic sub-directories that would launch my particular app without editing httpd.conf.  Is this achievable?

Comment: Why dont you just enable `Options +Index` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `VirtualDocumentRoot`.

In your case you can setup a development sub-domains to access your websites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testsites.localhost.com
    ServerAlias *.test.localhost.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/dev/%1/public
</VirtualHost>
```

Now if you access `http://project1.test.localhost.com` it will point you to `/var/www/dev/project1/public`, `http://project2.test.localhost.com` will point to `/var/www/dev/project2/public` and etc.

In order this to work, you have to also enable the module virtual_host_alias

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Note that you have to put entries in your `/etc/hosts` for your sub-domains and point them to be resolved by 127.0.0.1.

```
127.0.0.1    project1.test.localhost.com
127.0.0.1    project2.test.localhost.com
```

If you don't want to write an entry for each of your sub-domains in the hosts file you can consider to setup a simple DNS server, where you can wildcard all of your sub-domains `*.test.localhost.com` and tell them to resolve to 127.0.0.1

You can read more about dynamic virtual hosts [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating 'my_projects' directory inside your public folder (public, public_html, etc).

For example you can place Laravel1 and Laravel2 projects inside your 'my_projects' folder, then you can access your projects by typing '127.0.0.1/my_projects/Laravel1' and '127.0.0.1/my_projects/Laravel2'.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to main 2 level of directories for each sub-project one for public folder and other for laravel application.

Say for example you want to run several laravel apps inside 127.0.0.1/my_projects. You need to put different laravel instances (except its' public folder) in root let's call these apps laravel1, laravel2, laravel3 etc.

Now for each project you want under 127.0.0.1/my_projects create a subfolder under this, move contents of public folder of respective laravel app in this subfolder and edit index.php file to load appropriate bootstrap.php file. i.e. making its path to "../../laravel1/" or "../../laravel2/" etc.

Let me know if you have any questions. Will be happy to help.